Collect GCP metrics for GKE Security Posture
I have enabled the GKE Security Posture and I have added one of my clusters.
I am now able to view both Workload Vulnerabilities and Configuration issues.
I then switch to Monitoring and try to create a Dashboard that plots those 2 issues as they fluctuate over time. However I am unable to find such metrics.
Does GKE Security Posture produces metrics and if so what are they called?

No, GKE Security Posture itself doesn't directly expose metrics you can use in Cloud Monitoring to build a dashboard.
However, below is an alternate method of monitoring your GKE cluster's security posture -
Utilize the Security Posture Dashboard: While it lacks metrics for Monitoring, the Security Posture dashboard itself offers a visual representation of vulnerability and configuration issues over time. You may monitor trends and identify areas that require work.
For more information, please visit the link -
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/about-security-posture-dashboard#why-use
